# SQL JOIN match NULL column values

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, null, sql-delete

I am using a `JOIN` in MS SQL Server 2012 to delete records in one table that match records in another table using

```
DELETE t1
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
    ON 
    t1.[Column1] = t2.[Column1] 
    AND t1.[Column2] = t2.[Column2] 
    AND t1.[Column3] = t2.[Column3]
```

However, if columns in both tables contain `null` then they are not matched and deleted. How could I modify the query to match the records if both columns contained `null`, without adding specific checks for `null`

```
DELETE t1
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
    ON 
    t1.[Column1] = t2.[Column1] OR (t1.[Column1] is null and t2.[Column1] is null)
    AND t1.[Column2] = t2.[Column2] OR (t1.[Column2] is null and t2.[Column2] is null)
    AND t1.[Column3] = t2.[Column3] OR (t1.[Column3] is null and t2.[Column3] is null)
```

Comment: Use ISNULL to change nulls to some default value, like for INT default it to 0 if NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try the following:

```
DELETE t1
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
    ON 
    Isnull(t1.[Column1],'') = isnull(t2.[Column1],'')
    AND isnull(t1.[Column2],'') = isnull(t2.[Column2],'')
    AND isnull(t1.[Column3],'') = isnull(t2.[Column3],'');
```

Comment: Actually, the general rule is to use `''` because it can be converted to almost any type.

Comment: Thanks. I just assumed the columns were numeric for some reason. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` to make `=` treat two `null`s as equal.

Comment: Never really knew what the `ANSI NULLS` setting was doing, thanks for this. +1 from me.

Comment: Can this be done on a per script basis? I just tried it within my script and got `'ANSI' is not a recognized SET option.`

Comment: @webworm sorry about that typo - it's supposed to be `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, with an underscore between `ANSI` and `NULLS`.

Comment: I used `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` in the script and although no error occurred it still did not match columns that both contained `null` values

Answer (score 3):

This is a real problem, because SQL Server does not have a `NULL`-safe comparison operator.  The ANSI standard operator is `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.

The problem with `OR` is that it precludes the use of indexes.  The problem with `ISNULL()` is the same.  So, if your tables have any size, you want to avoid them.

One thing you can do is set the values to a default.  I don't know what defaults avoid existing values, but this could look like:

```
update table1
    set column1 = coalesce(column1, ''),  -- for strings
        column2 = coalesce(column2, -1),  -- for numbers
        column3 = coalesce(column3, cast('1900-01-01' as date))  -- for dates
    where column1 is null or column2 is null or column3 is null;
```

You would need to do this on both tables.  You can then recuperate the `NULL` values after the delete.

Actually, in SQL Server, you can add computed columns:

```
alter table1 add column1_notnull as (coalesce(column1, '')) persisted;  -- or whatever
```

Then you can create an index on them:

```
create index idx_table1_columns_123_notnull on table1(column1_notnull, column2_notnull, column3_notnull);
```

And repeat for `table2`.

Then your first query will work (using the `_notnull` columns of course) and make use of the index for performance.